# User-specified scripts and output folders for sqlcmd in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, sqlcmd

Currently, the below For/Do loop goes through all SQL files that are in *the same folder* as the batch file itself and outputs the CSVs to a user-specified folder (`%OUTPUTFOLDER%` is actually created earlier in the batch file as a subfolder of `%SCRIPTFOLDER%`, which is specified by the user):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%S IN (
    'DIR /B "%SCRIPTFOLDER%\*.sql" '
) DO (
    echo Reading scripts from: %SCRIPTFOLDER%\*.sql
    echo Script: %%~fS
    echo Output: %OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv
    sqlcmd -b -S %INSTANCE% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%~fS" -s "|" -o "%OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv" -W
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO errorhandling
    ECHO %%~nS.csv successfully created
)
```

For a visual example, if I had the folder structure

```
C:\Extract\extract.bat
C:\Extract\Scripts\
C:\Extract\Output\
```

The variable `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` is set by the user and is the folder that, you guessed it, holds the scripts. But the batch file has to be in that folder, too. I need to change this so that the scripts do not have to be in the same folder as the batch file. I.e. the user can specify both `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` and `%OUTPUTFOLDER%`

Due to the output of `echo Script: %%fS`, I'm guessing that's what I need to change - possibly what's in the `FOR` line as well, but I'm not seeing how exactly to do that.

Comment: `for %%S in ("%SCRIPTFOLDER\*.sql")`, of course, instead of the bizarre attempt to parse the output of `dir`. First, `setlocal` (so that the `cd` stays local.) And then `cd /d "%~dpS"` before `sqlcmd`.

Comment: @AlexP "bizarre"? I'm just piecing this together as I figure batch-scripting out! :) Thanks, Alex, I'll work with your suggestion.

Comment: I apologize for my brusqueness; sometimes I forget that for many people the baroque scripting language of `Cmd.exe` is something new. "Bizarre" was simply because the *primary* function of `for` is to iterate over a set of files; `for %%f in (*.txt) do` is as basic as it gets. Everything else (`for /f`, `for /l`, `for /r`) came much later. (Which is, of course, not important *today*...)

Comment: No offense taken. I took it as a joke :) I'm not surprised at all that my code looks "bizarre" to someone more experienced!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `"the batch file has to be in that folder, too"`. As I can see from your code, the batch file is not in the exact same folder as the `Scripts` folder and it is referencing scripts by the path specified by `%SCRIPTFOLDER%`. Do you mean that you want the location of batch file to be completely independent of the location of the user specified path for  `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` and `%OUTPUTFOLDER%`? e.g. to be able to place batch file anywhere in the system even in different drive?

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to clarify how user specifies the path for `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` and `%OUTPUTFOLDER%`; Does the user specifies a fully qualified path e.g. `C:\Extract\Scripts` or specifies a path relative to some predefined base path e.g. user specifies `Scripts` as the folder but the base path is `C:\Extract` . In other words if you execute `echo %OUTPUTFOLDER%` which one will be printed? `C:\Extract\Scripts` or `Scripts` ?

Comment: @AlexP I think changing to the same directory on every iteration of the for loop is not a good idea. Placing `for %%S in ("%SCRIPTFOLDER%") do cd /d "%%~fS"` outside of the main loop, and changing the main loop to `for %%S in ("*.sql")` should better serve your idea. However I'm not sure if that addresses the problem because if the path of `%SCRIPTFOLDER%` is relative (as the full path is obtained with the help of `FOR` modifiers) then the location of the batch file can not be arbitrary and the usage of `/d` switch for the `cd` command will be pointless.